How do I configure Instagram to automatically post on Threads?
I manage several business related Instagram accounts where subsequently I created a Threads account out of them. They are somehow linked, because you see the links to the Threads account in the Instagram account, and viceversa. But recently, I found that one of them automatically posts to Threads.
I don't remember configuring anything, but I doubt Instagram set this feature automatically, perhaps I did it without realizing it. The thing is, now I would like all the accounts to automatically post to their respective Threads accounts.
Can this be configured? How/where do I set that?
